# For each $n$ determine whether $S_n$ (1) and $D_n$ (2) are simple or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

For each `n` determine whether  $S_n$ (1) and $D_n$ (2) are simple or not.

So I know that a group is called a simple group if that group has no proper nontrivial normal subgroups.

(1) First of all I need to find if $S_n$ has normal subgroups. Am I right?

In one example I found that $A_n$ is normal subgroup of $S_n$. How should I check it? $|S_n|=n!$ and $|A_n|=n!/2$ so $[S_n:A_n]=2$ I think $A_n$ is a subgroup if index $2$ in $S_n$. So $S_n$ is not simple?

(2) I am not sure if I was right in (1), but with this I have no idea what to do. I only know that $D_n=\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,...,\alpha^{n-1},\beta,\alpha\beta,...,\alpha^{n-1}\beta |\alpha^n=\beta^2=1, \beta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}\beta \}$.

Comment: I think your presentation for $D_n$ is not correct. It should be $\beta^2=1$ and $\beta \alpha= \alpha^{-1} \beta$.

Comment: @AlanWang, yes, I made a mistake. Thank you

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct idea.

For $n>2$, $S_n$ has a proper normal subgroup $A_n$. So $S_n$ is not simple. However, $S_2=Z_2$ is simple.

For dihedral group, consider the subgroup $\langle \alpha \rangle$. Since $|\alpha|=n$, $|D_n:\langle \alpha \rangle|=2$, hence $\langle \alpha \rangle$ is a proper normal subgroup of $D_n$ when $n>2$.  Similarly, $D_2=Z_2$ is simple.

Comment: I just whant to make sure. $\langle a \rangle= \{ 1, \alpha,...,\alpha^{n-1}\}$? What if I will take $\langle \beta \rangle$?

Comment: Yes $\langle \alpha \rangle =\{ 1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{n-1} \}$, while \langle \beta \rangle =\{ 1,\beta \}. You can check for $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}$ to conclude that it is not a normal subgroup of $D_n$.

Comment: thank you. And last question is if with $A_n$ group $S_n$ is not simple, and with $Z_2$ is simpe. So why we cannot say that $S_n$ is simple. Or it is because if we can find at least one normal subgroup than group $S_n$ is not simple?

Comment: Yes, for $S_2$ you cannot find any nontrivial proper normal subgroup so it is trivial.